# redirecting htaccess to a url from a variable

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

We move our images to a cdn server.
In the original site we used a php file to shrink the images.
This gramer used by mobile apps. Example: http://example.com/imageget.php?width=351&height=245&image=http://example.com/image.jpg

Now that we use cdn I need to create an htaccess to explode the the URL from the var image and redirect it to that URL. Is it posible?

Comment: That example URL is invalid. The embedded URL would have to be url encoded.

Comment: Apart from that: what sense does it make to use a fast CDN, but route requests to that through a local server?

Comment: @arkascha Because if done right, the CDN only needs to request it once with given parameters and can cache it for infinity.

Answer (score 0):

A friend help me and found this to be working

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^width=\d+&height=\d+&image=(.*)(/images)(.*)
RewriteRule ^ %1%3? [R=301]